# Naming an Ember.Component subclass

Tags: ember.js

I have a template with an id of `components/preview/image`. I want to create a subclass of Ember.Component that corresponds to this template.

If the template had an id of `components/image`, I could create a subclass of Ember.Component called `ImageComponent`.

The `preview/` nesting inside of `components/` is throwing a wrench into my plans. Preferably, I would like to name the component `PreviewImageComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

The naming is a convention- you must use a dash and not underscore in the name.  Create your template with the id `components/preview-image` and use the following template tag:

```
{{preview-image url=foo}}
```

and then create your component like this:

```
App.PreviewImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    // implementation here
});
```

EDIT:  Just to be really clear:  a dash somewhere in the name is **required**